# Vue Buefy table with multiple row statuses

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-table, buefy

Buefy tables has a setting where you can choose what rows are highlighted by a specific colour depending on a variable in the row.

```
            :row-class="(row, index) => row.variable === x && 'is-info'">
```

and adding style for the specific row-class:

```
<style>
    .is-info' {
      background: #FF8C4B;
    }
```

This works, and i can highlight all rows with x as their variables. But consider if I have a table with multiple variables X, Y ,Z. And i want all the ones with variable value of X to be highlighted blue and the ones with Y to be red. Is this possible? I cant seem to find any examples anywhere.

This is my current data section of the vue page:

```
export default {
  name: "Demo",
  data: () => {
    data: () => {
return {
  loading: null,
  alphabets: [],
  className:{
    'x': '.bg-danger',
    'y': '.bg-success'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it can be done:

```
:row-class="(row, index) => row.alphabet === 'x' && 'is-x' || row.alphabet === 'y' && 'is-y' || row.alphabet === 'z' && 'is-z'"
```

and then style it

```
<style>
  .is-x{
    background: #f15462;
  }
  .is-y{
    background: #f5bb1a;
  }
  .is-z{
    background: #3bdc5e;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define class map in data object as follows:

```
:row-class="(row, index) => className[row.variable]">

data: ()=> ({className: {
x:'info',
y:'primary'
z:'warning'

}})
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, should i change info, primary and warning with html colours?

Comment: No,  it should be replaced with contextual classes like bg-primary,  bg-info or any custom class that you have/can style. You can even use multiple classes `y: 'bg-primary text-light'`

Comment: this might be a vue thing, but should i put classname {...} inside return?        
data: () => {
    return {
      loading: null,
      alphabets: [],
      className:{
        'x': '.bg-danger',
        'y': '.bg-success'
      },
    };

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I missed the curly brackets